# How to test Flink Global Window with Trigger And Evictor

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a pipeline which use Flink Global Window with custom Trigger based on Event Time (from timestamp on arriving element) and Evictor which cut unnecessary elements from the window and pass it to the ProcessFunction,

something like:

```
 public SingleOutputStreamOperator<Results> processElements(DataStream<Elements> inputStream) {
 return inputStream
                .keyBy(Elements::getId)
                .window(GlobalWindows.create())
                .trigger(new CustomTrigger())
                .evictor(new CustomEvictor())
                .process(new MyWindowProcessFunction())
                .name("Process")
                .uid("process-elements")
                .returns(Results.class);    
}

    public void executePipelineFlow(StreamExecutionEnvironment env) throws Exception {
        DataStream<Elements> inputStream = getInputStream(env);
        DataStream<Results> processedInput = processElements(inputStream);
        applySink(processedInput);
}
```

I know i can test MyWindowProcessFunction with TestHarness which provide Watermark manipulation but i need to test whole flow, Trigger+Evictor+ProcessFunction.

Also i try some kind of timed SourceFunction with use of Thread.sleep() but my pipeline work in event time and this wont work if i had 1000 elements in test stream (because test will take couple of hours).

My question is, how i can unit test my whole `processElements` method?

I cant find any test examples for my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might look at how the [end-to-end integration tests for the windowing exercise in the Flink training](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/hourly-tips/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/training/exercises/hourlytips/HourlyTipsTest.java) are implemented as an example. This exercise isn't using GlobalWindows or custom triggering, etc, but you can use this overall approach to test any pipeline.

The one thing that's maybe less than ideal about this approach is how it handles watermarking. The applications being tested are using the default periodic watermarking strategy, wherein watermarks are generated every 200msec. Since the tests don't run that long, the only watermark that's actually generated is the one that comes at the end of every job with bounded inputs. This works, but isn't quite the same as what will happen in production. (Is this why you were thinking of having your test source sleep between events?)

BTW, these tests in the Flink training repo are made slightly more complex than is ordinarily necessary, because these tests are used to provide coverage for the Java and the Scala implementations of both the exercises and solutions.

Comment: @DavidAndersion thanks for answer and yes, the ascending of watermark is the reason why i use Thread.sleep() between events. Without it, even if my test was in EventTime, and my Watermark Assigner (just simply taking timestamp from Event) where implemented in tests, the watermarks in Evictor and Trigger was always min Long (-9223372036854775808) and the logic in them was not applied because all events has the same watermark. When i use sleep(), only the first couple of events where min Long and the rest was good.

Comment: So that will be ok but i have test case with ~1000 of events and the sleep time 50ms so i cant do that. I will check your link but if there is a problem with watermarking idk it will help me much.

Comment: Let me try to be clearer: there's no problem with watermarks, and in my opinion, there's no reason to sleep in the source. All that should matter is the event-time timestamps, not the rate at which the events are processed.

Comment: In documentation (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/testing/) in the last "Testing Flink Jobs" section we can read: "You can implement a custom parallel source function for emitting watermarks if your job uses event time timers." So there is a way to create a SourceFunction with ability to generate proper watermarks in case like mine?

Comment: Sure. A SourceFunction can use `SourceFunction.SourceContext#emitWatermark(Watermark mark)` to emit Watermarks.